# Solution to insert sub-query with additional group by

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to merge two working SQL query's in Oracle SQL Developer but can't seem to get the sub's Group By's to play nicely. I want/expect to see separate totals for each row but I'm getting an overall total for all rows.

I tried adding the second query as sub-query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT SOURCE,   
sum(case when status = 'C1' then 1 else 0 end) as "C1",
sum(case when status = 'C2' then 1 else 0 end) as "C2",
sum(case when status = 'C3' then 1 else 0 end) as "C3",
sum(case when status = 'C4' then 1 else 0 end) as "C4",
sum(case when status = 'C5' then 1 else 0 end) as "C5" 
FROM TABLE.req 
GROUP BY SOURCE 
ORDER BY SOURCE;
```

---

Query 2 to be added to the above:

```
SELECT SOURCE, COUNT(REQ.SOURCE) AS "Done in 7 Days"
FROM TABLE.req REQ
    JOIN TABLE.audit AUD ON REQ.ROW_ID = AUD.RECORD_ID
WHERE (AUD.LAST_UPD - REQ.CREATED) <= 7 
    AND REQ.STATUS = 'Complete'
    GROUP BY SOURCE;
```

---

Tried Sub-Query:

```
SELECT SOURCE,   
sum(case when status = 'C1' then 1 else 0 end) as "C1",
sum(case when status = 'C2' then 1 else 0 end) as "C2",
sum(case when status = 'C3' then 1 else 0 end) as "C3",
sum(case when status = 'C4' then 1 else 0 end) as "C4",
sum(case when status = 'C5' then 1 else 0 end) as "C5"    
(SELECT SOURCE, COUNT(REQ.SOURCE) 
FROM TABLE.req REQ
    JOIN TABLE.audit AUD ON REQ.ROW_ID = AUD.RECORD_ID
WHERE (AUD.LAST_UPD - REQ.CREATED) <= 7 
    AND REQ.STATUS = 'Complete'
GROUP BY SOURCE) AS "Done in 7"
FROM TABLE.req 
GROUP BY SOURCE 
ORDER BY SOURCE;


Query 1 returns:

A   0   0   0   0   0
B   0   0   3026    26  2461
C   0   0   0   0   0
D   3   39  2   1   19
E   0   0   61156   0   79430

Query 2 returns:

A   2906
B   10
C   28
D   7
E       0
```

ACTUAL:
   Sub-Query returns the additional Column BUT it's being totaled

```
A   0   0   0   0   0           2951
B   0   0   3026    26  2461    2951
C   0   0   0   0   0           2951
D   3   39  2   1   19          2951
E   0   0   61156   0   79430   2951
```

EXPECTED:
   Sub-Query returns the additional Column BUT it's being totaled

```
A   0   0   0   0   0           2906
B   0   0   3026    26  2461    10
C   0   0   0   0   0           28
D   3   39  2   1   19          7
E   0   0   61156   0   79430   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT SOURCE,   
       sum(case when status = 'C1' then 1 else 0 end) as "C1",
       sum(case when status = 'C2' then 1 else 0 end) as "C2",
       sum(case when status = 'C3' then 1 else 0 end) as "C3",
       sum(case when status = 'C4' then 1 else 0 end) as "C4",
       sum(case when status = 'C5' then 1 else 0 end) as "C5",  
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM TABLE.req REQ r2 JOIN
             TABLE.audit a
             ON r2.ROW_ID = a.RECORD_ID
       WHERE r2.SOURCE = r.SOURCE AND
             (a.LAST_UPD - r2.CREATED) <= 7 AND
             r2.STATUS = 'Complete'
      )
FROM TABLE.req  r
GROUP BY SOURCE 
ORDER BY SOURCE;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but that errors out on that last WHERE: "from keyword not found where expected"  Might the syntax be incorrect?

Comment: @Rhelm. . . That was a typo.  That detritus should not be in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  However, it also returns the totals down the entire column.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Rhelm . . . The match on `source` in the correlation clause should result in the values being different.